How does the character from Ramayana and Mahabharata, Hanuman's understanding of niyati affect his relationships with other characters?
The character of Hanuman, primarily known from the Hindu epics Ramayana and Mahabharata, embodies profound themes of duty (dharma), righteousness, and the moral dilemmas that arise from these concepts.
While niyati influences Hanuman's choices, it also presents him with moral dilemmas. He must navigate the complexities of duty and righteousness, particularly when faced with the consequences of his actions. His understanding of fate (niyati) influences his decisions. He recognizes that the war is part of a divine plan and that intervening directly could disrupt the balance of dharma. This awareness leads him to act in ways that uphold righteousness without undermining the necessary trials the Pandavas must face.
Hanuman serves as a model for ideal behavior, demonstrating how to navigate the challenges of duty and righteousness. His choices reflect a balance between personal desires and the greater good, making him a timeless figure in discussions of ethics and morality in Hindu philosophy.
How does his understanding of niyati affect his relationships with other characters?

Can you make the question any more specific? I've also removed the link, since it doesn't talk about Hanuman's actions.

@cmw What should be more specific?

For those not in the known, what work are you discussing, what characters would he interact with, examples of these moral dilemmas, why would you characterize him regarding fate and dharma, etc. Contextualizing the question, explaining the motivation for the question, and providing guidance as to what you're actually looking for would make for a compelling question. As it is now, it's too broad. Does that make sense?

I don't have an answer, I'm not an expert in this field. A question this broad and nuanced might take a long time to get an answer, though, judging by others I've seen. Good luck.

A bounty was premature. As I mentioned, it might take a while for someone who knows what they're talking about to answer this. Good luck.
